# KeyExchange and ciphers in postfix, enforcing a specific key for exchange

Tags: ssl, postfix

My mailserver has troubles in the TLS handshake with a particular other mailserver.

Doing some tests it turns out that the two servers do not have ciphers in common.
Now the problem is that there are ciphersuites in common but the KeyExchange differs. I'll show it in a table to be more clear:

```
My server:
excode  Cipher Suite Name (OpenSSL)       KeyExch.   Encryption

xc028   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384           ECDH 256   AES   
xc014   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA              ECDH 256   AES   
x9f     DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384         DH 2048    AESGCM
x6b     DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256             DH 2048    AES   
x39     DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA                DH 2048    AES   

Other server:
xc024   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384         ECDH 256   AES    
xc00a   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA            ECDH 256   AES    
xc032   ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384        ECDH/RSA   AESGCM 
xc02a   ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384            ECDH/RSA   AES    
xc00f   ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA               ECDH/RSA   AES
```

If I'm not mistaken the trouble is that the first two ciphers differs due to them using a ECDSA certificate, and that is nothing I can do about. But the last three ciphers differ because our servers use a different key exchange method. So the question is, how can I force or change the key exchange method used by my box in connection with the ciphers in question for it to match the other server's. Or, in other words, what decides which method is used in the keyExchange.

I use postfix 3.1.0 and openssl 1.0.2g

Comment: Just make the SMTP client component support ciphersuites available on the SMTP server it connects to. Key exchange is part of the ciphersuite.

Comment: The communication problem is between two servers, they cannot complete the TLS handshake. I have no control on the other server. So you are telling me to just make te ciphersuite match those of the other server, but this is actually my question. I've pointed out where the difference is, and it is in the key used for the exchange, but I don't know how to specify this in postfix.

Comment: SMTP is a client-server protocol. When delivering mail to a next-hop server, your server acts as a client.

Comment: Yes I got that, I was just trying to avoid any misunderstandings. The difference on postfix being  whether one sets  smtp_xxx config params or smtpd_xxx ditto. However the question remains unanswered.

Comment: I'm not sure what "different key" you are talking about. The first two ciphers differ in the public key algorithm used within the server certificate. The difference with the last three ciphers is between the key exchange method, i.e. DHE vs. ECDHE. This is not about a "different key". The fix is to make your server to offer __as a SMTP client__ the ciphers supported by the other server, i.e. set `smtp_tls_ciphers` accordingly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Or unset it, because there shouldn't be any problem with the default setting.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for pointing out the mistake about the exchange method, now the text is corrected. In the meanwhile I've tested the default settings for high strength and medium strength without obtaining that particular combination. I see that "openssl ciphers" gives me those combinations but I wonder whether as for the ECDSA case (that is only offered when the server certificate is ECDSA), there might be other factors decding which exchange method is used.
What I want is ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Comment: *"What I want is ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"* - this cipher expects a certificate with an RSA public key. It cannot be used with a server using ECC public key in the certificate (i.e. ECDSA). And have you've tried to simply not specifically configure the ciphers as recommended by Esa Jokinen? The defaults are usually fairly good.